# Lucee - slow start up

Tags: lucee

I have a Lucee installation in which there are ~ 30 GB of documents (Word, Excel, etc.) in a directory in the web root.

It's taking Lucee about 10 minutes to start up. This effect is absent on the development server that doesn't have all the documents.

Anyone know what's going on? Is Lucee scanning for .cfm files? Is there a way to tell it to ignore the Documents directory?

Comment: Have you researched this a bit? What resource is Lucee using mostly when it starts up? How does memory look? I'm guessing Tomcat is just Jar scanning your documents folder and it's taking some time, but additional info would would make it so we could give you a more specific answer. General advice to boost startup time is here: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp

Comment: I don't have admin access to the server (SAs work for a different organization), so my information is limited. All I know for sure is that the start up time is vastly different on the two servers, and that the only difference is the large Documents directory on the production server, that is empty on the dev server. Incidentally, the Documents directory is all user data - nothing that would be of actual use to Tomcat or Lucee. Thanks for the reference - I'll check that out.

Comment: Hmm... how are you expected to diagnose & fix something without access to do so? Seems like you're already in a losing scenario to me. Sorry to hear it my friend.

Comment: Yes - not an ideal situation. Thanks for the sympathy as well as the help!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The Documents directory turned out to be a red herring. The real culprit was some authentication code containing a cfapplication call with "clientstorage = file" rather than cookies. Not sure why that ever seemed like a good idea, but it apparently caused Lucee to create 256 directories containing ~300,000 small files in WEB-INF/lucee/clientscope/.

After the Sys. Admin. deleted all that junk, switched to clientstorage = cookies, and restarted Lucee, start-up was lightning fast.

Hopefully this will help someone else one day...